# What is the meaning of "universal: true" from a slate.js example?

Tags: slate

What is the "***universal: true***" statement in the following code for?

```
isAziendaMarkActive(editor) {
    const [match] = Editor.nodes(editor, {
    match: n => n.isAzienda === true,
    universal: true,
})
```

Thanks so much,
Elena

Answer (score 0):

Setting `universal: true` returns the matching nodes if and only if *all* of the selected nodes match your query.

So, in your case, `isAziendaMarkActive()` would return false for the following selection:

```
<AziendaMark> A </AziendaMark>   B   <AziendaMark> C </AziendaMark>
```

but true for this:

```
<AziendaMark> A B C </AziendaMark>
```

See: https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/3248#issue-533523682